# Why doesn't "ssh-keygen -R" remove the host from ~/.ssh/known_hosts

Tags: ssh

It seems that ssh-keygen is unable to identify the host that I've requested to remove from the hosts file.

```sh
$ ssh-keygen -R 'leviathan.labs.overthewire.org'
Host leviathan.labs.overthewire.org not found in /Users/zachriggle/.ssh/known_hosts
```

But the host is clearly in the `known_hosts` file:

```
$ grep leviathan.labs.overthewire.org ~/.ssh/known_hosts
[leviathan.labs.overthewire.org]:2223 ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIDPNAn6LOV1QtSqlnnXz6eECuznq5bNIe6DLFpMNZMEI
```

This is only caught by Paramiko, but it seems that it ought to be removed.

```py
>>> from pwn import *
>>> ssh(user='leviathan0', password='leviathan0', host='leviathan.labs.overthewire.org', port=2223)
[x] Connecting to leviathan.labs.overthewire.org on port 2223
[-] Connecting to leviathan.labs.overthewire.org on port 2223: Failed
[!] SSH host key validation has failed for 'leviathan.labs.overthewire.org'
    If you want to trust this new SSH key, you should manually run the command:
    $ ssh-keygen -R 'leviathan.labs.overthewire.org'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zachriggle/pwntools/pwnlib/tubes/ssh.py", line 665, in __init__
    self.client.connect(host, port, user, password, key, keyfiles, self.timeout, compress = True)
  File "/Users/zachriggle/.pyenv/versions/3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 423, in connect
    raise BadHostKeyException(hostname, server_key, our_key)
paramiko.ssh_exception.BadHostKeyException: Host key for server 'leviathan.labs.overthewire.org' does not match: got 'AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIIJwHwzTXHJomqOQfM8emYvBLMkHQrtG5nBz6MP/No4O', expected 'AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIDPNAn6LOV1QtSqlnnXz6eECuznq5bNIe6DLFpMNZMEI'
```

OpenSSH happily accepts the new host key, with a simple prompt.

```
$ ssh level0@leviathan.labs.overthewire.org
The authenticity of host 'leviathan.labs.overthewire.org (176.9.9.172)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:jMsE6D2121JkEDk3fqlcvkx/N42Q0jdY0KY+g1oaPEQ.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Why doesn't `ssh-keygen` remove this line?  Why doesn't OpenSSH catch that there is a known hostly for ECDSA for this named host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's *not the same entry.* The entry you're trying to remove is for port 22 only – the entry you have in the file is for port 2223. Likewise, you're telling OpenSSH to connect on port 22 but Paramiko on port 2223.

The pwn.ssh message is incomplete and should have suggested `ssh-keygen -R '[foo]:2223'`.

Most SSH clients track hostkeys per host:port pair, as it is much more common to have multiple hosts reachable at a single address (using NAT port-forwarding) than to have a single sshd listening on multiple ports. This applies even to "leviathan.labs.overthewire.org", which has two different sshd instances (with different hostkeys) on ports 22 and 2223.